# Issue in renaming the multiple aggregation outcome columns in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

I got a question regarding the multiple aggregation in pandas.

Originally I have a dataset which shows the oil price, and the detail is as follows:
[image]

And the head of the dataset is as follows:

[image]

What I want to do here is to get the mean and standard deviation for each quarter of the year 2014. And the ideal output is as follows:

[image]

In my script, I have already created the quarter info by doing so .
[image]

**However, one thing that I do not understand here:**

If I tried to use this command to do so

```
brent[brent.index.year == 2014].groupby('quarter').agg({"average_price": np.mean, "std_price": np.std})
```

I got an error as follows:
[image]

And if I use the following script, then it works

```
brent[brent.index.year == 2014].groupby('quarter').agg(average_price=('Price','mean'), 
                                                   std_price=('Price','std'))
```

[image]

So the questions are:

- What's wrong with the first approach here?
- And why do we need to use the second approach here?

Thank you all for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with the first approach here?

There is passed dict, so pandas looking for columns from keys `average_price`, `std_price` and because not exist in DataFrame if return error.

Possible solution is specified column after groupby and pass list of tuples for specified new columns names with aggregate functions:

```
brent[brent.index.year == 2014].groupby('quarter')['Price'].agg([('average_price','mean'),('std_price',np.std)])
```

It is possible, because for one column `Price` is possible defined multiple columns names.

In later pandas versions are used [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
brent[brent.index.year == 2014].groupby('quarter').agg(average_price=('Price','mean'), 
                                                      std_price=('Price',np.std))
```

Here is logic - for each aggregation is defined nw column name with aggregate column and aggregate function. So is possible aggregate multiple columns with different functions:

```
brent[brent.index.year == 2014].groupby('quarter').agg(average_price=('Price','mean'), 
                                                      std_price=('Price',np.std),
                                                      sumQ=('quarter','sum'))
```

Notice, `np.std` has default `ddof=0` and pandas `std` has `ddof=1`, so different outputs.